# VBA index match or something else

Tags: excel, vba

I need to reference a unique text string on 2 different worksheets (Master and WI pull) and when a match is found, I need to populate a different column on the 'Master' sheet with data from another column on the WI pull.

I will only need it to do this when the Master sheet destination cell is blank, otherwise it should move to the right 1 cell and again populate if it's blank. It does this for 3 columns only. If all 3 cells in the 3 columns of the same row are none blank, it should do nothing. Once it has done this, it needs to move down 1 cell to repeat.

For example:
Match cells in column 'H' from the WI pull with cells in column 'A' from the Master sheet.

Once a match is made, copy 'C' from the same row reference in WI pull into 'W' on the Master sheet providing it's blank otherwise copy it into 'X' if that is blank otherwise copy it into 'Y' if that is blank otherwise do not copy and move down one cell in 'H' on WI pull and repeat the process.

I have this code which does not look for blanks ( I was going to modify the code once I'd got it to work ), however it returns zero's in the destination cell all the way down.

```
 Sub test()
 Dim masterWorkbook As Workbook
 Set masterWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

 Dim masterSheet As Worksheet
 Dim importedSheet As Worksheet
 Set masterSheet = masterWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
 Set importedSheet = masterWorkbook.Worksheets("WI pull")

 masterSheet.Range("W7:W1068").Formula = _
 "=INDIRECT(""importedSheet!C"" & INDEX(MATCH(A1,importedSheet!H:H,0),0,0))"

 masterSheet.Range("W7:W1068").Value = masterSheet.Range("W7:W1068").Value
 End Sub
```

Help appreciated